# android ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I have an app which use Apache POI. The Build is successfully but when I run the code there is an error (I use Android Studio 2.1) :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.XSDatatype
```

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.lionel.xls_test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
* Created by Lionel on 31/07/2016.
*/
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView texte = null;

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
* See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
*/


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
texte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);

try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/test.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
    Row row = sheet.getRow(cr.getRow());
    Cell cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());
    String name = cell.getStringCellValue();
    texte.setText(name);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
}
```

I think that i implemented all the .jar files of POI Apache, here the dependencies :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile project(':poi-3.14-20160307')
compile project(':poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307')
compile project(':poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307')
compile project(':xmlbeans-2.6.0')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
compile project(':dom4j-1.6.1')
compile project(':poi-excelant-3.14-20160307')
compile project(':poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307')
compile project(':commons-codec-1.10')
compile project(':commons-logging-1.2')
compile project(':log4j-1.2.17')
compile project(':junit-4.12')
}
```

Is there something missing in my code ? Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You obviously need to add [xsdlib](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd/xsdlib/2013.2) as runtime dependency to your project

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. But what is the procedure to add xsdlib as run time dependency to my project (I'm beginner with Android)

Comment: I use Android Studio 2.1.1. Thanks you.

Comment: the dependency manager in Android Studio is Gradle so you should add in your dependencies runtime group: 'com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd', name: 'xsdlib', version: '2013.2' read this for more details https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

Comment: I added compile group: 'com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd', name: 'xsdlib', version: '2013.2' in the dependenciesof the Gradle.

Comment: I added  : compile group: 'com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd', name: 'xsdlib', version: '2013.2' in the dependencies of the Gradle. Now when i run the code, there is the following error : 'code' Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option. thanks you for your help.

Comment: have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381417/compile-error-jsr-ret-are-not-supported-with-computeframes-option?

Comment: Thanks you for this link. "Removing the following compiler flags fixes the error:

-source 1.5 -target 1.5". How to do that on Android Studio. If it doesn't fix the error, I will try to use Eclipse. Can you tell me how to add the xsdlib as runtime dependency in an Eclipse project ? Thanks you for your help.

Comment: simply download the jar file from this link http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/msv/datatype/xsd/xsdlib/2013.2/xsdlib-2013.2.jar and add it to your eclipse project

Comment: thanks you for this file. But in Eclipse, the file must be added in the folder "Android private libraries", "Android Dependencies", "Referenced libraries", "libs" ..?